# Define particular slot as separate class R

Tags: r, class, object

My aim is to define one of the slots of class Security as another class Quote.

First I define class Quote:

```
Quote <- setClass("Quote", slots = c(Last = "numeric", Settle = "numeric"))
```

Then I am trying to define class Security as following:

```
Security <- setClass("Security", slots = c(Name = "character", Price = "Quote"))
```

Finally I am trying to create constructor for class Security:

```
Security <- function(Name = character(), Last = numeric(), Settle = numeric()) 
 new("Security", Name = Name, Price@Last = Last, Price@Settle = Settle)
```

Unfortunately, this code doesn't work...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still trying to learn S4, and I see that a recognized expert has already given an answer, so I'm mostly posting this as an example for critique:

```
.Quote <- setClass("Quote", slots = c(Last = "numeric", Settle = "numeric"))
.Security <- setClass("Security", slots = c(Name = "character", Price = "Quote"))
 aNewSecurity <- .Security(Name = "newSec", 
                           Price = .Quote(Last =20, Settle = 40) )
 aNewSecurity
An object of class "Security"
Slot "Name":
[1] "newSec"

Slot "Price":
An object of class "Quote"
Slot "Last":
[1] 20

Slot "Settle":
[1] 40
```

I'm not sufficiently knowledgeable to know if separating Quote items from Security items is needed in this domain.

Comment: Appreciate the check but almost everything I understand about this topic was gleaned by reading MartinMorgan's SO posts on the topic of S$ methods, so it might be more appropriately reassigned to his.

Answer (score 1):

If offering the user a constructor named `Security`, make sure the default constructor is named differently

```
.Security <- setClass("Security", slots = c(Name = "character", Price = "Quote"))
```

In your own constructor, create the slot instance as an argument to default constructor; use `...` to allow for class inheritance

```
Security <- 
    function(Name = character(), Last = numeric(), Settle = numeric(), ...)
{
    .Security(Name=Name, Price=Quote(Last=Last, Settle=Settle), ...)
}
```

Comment: That looks a bit circular. Is it supposed to be that way?